# RegeX for a range and limit together

Tags: regex

I am new to regeX and I am looking for a expression which satisfy the below condition

1. should validate numbers only. decimal is not accepted.(eg :123, 11, 1025,0548)
2. should not greater than 7 digits

I tried the below regeX

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

but it works fine for numbers which greater than 0.

and then I tried

```
 ^[1-9][0-9]\d{1,7}$
```

but it accept if the digits is greater than 2 numbers. when I give `12` it returns `false`. when I give `123` it returns `true`

and when I give `0124` this will also return `false`

please refer the below points also for different inputs

1. 1, 12, 432, 12414, 1234567 etc all are valid inputs. its greater than 0 and max length is 7
2. 01, 0121, 0000001 etc are also valid. 0000001 is greater than 0.
3. 0, 12345678 etc are invalid, because it should not accept less than 0 or length greater than 7
4. all negative values are invalid, all characters are invalid

Comment: Is there something wrong with `^\d{7}$` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not working. I dont want to accept if the value is `0`. when I give `0` it returns false.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not working. I gave input `0121`. it should accept. please read my questions

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Very bad dupe target. This is well put together question an not answerable by the target.

Comment: Now, it is correct.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I saw that answer too, but it doesn't satisfied me. sorry.

Comment: Ok, since you accepted `^(?!0+$)\d{1,7}$` all you need is a lookaround to exclude an all  zero input. I changed the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead for this. This pattern will work fine:

```
^(?!0+$)\d{1,7}$
```

Explanation:

- `^(?!0+$)` negative lookahead, which checks that the string is not all `0`s. A *negative* lookahead means, that if this matches, the whole pattern will *not* match.
- `^       \d{1,7}$` checks that the string consists of 1 to 7 characters, which all are numbers.

(I'm reusing the `^` anchor for both the lookahead and the actual pattern, because they can share it, since the lookahead is at the start. The `^` could also be added to the lookahead: `(?!^0+$)`, but it wouldn't affect anything.)

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2i7w9M/6)

Comment: it is working fine. can you please explain what it does? it would be helpful

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran Added an explanation :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I can apply this to other area also.

Answer (score 1):

You could us a positive lookahead `(?=[0-9]*[1-9])` if supported to assert at least a digit 1-9 and then match 1- 7 digits.

```
^(?=[0-9]*[1-9])[0-9]{1,7}$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` [Positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), assert what is on the right is

  - `[0-9]*[1-9]` Match 0+ times a digit 0-9, then a digit 1-9
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[0-9]{1,7}` Match a digit 0-9 1-7 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hyxziT/1)

Comment: it is working fine. can you please explain what it does? it would be helpful

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran I have added an explanation about the separate parts.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and I understood. but sorry I accepted other answer because that is more convincing me.

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran No problem at all, good luck!